# Let nginx store html fragments to memcached

Tags: html, caching, nginx, memcached, fragment

Currently making a global volunteer site, and the webpages will more or less have a lot of static content, such as the navigation page, header and footer.

What I was wondering if it were possible to somehow instruct nginx to store these static files to memcache. I've seen a variety of methods to add values to memcache (whether it involves PHP, python, or enchanced_memcached_module on nginx), but I cannot seem to find a way to use the memcached module (enhanced or the original one) to someone parse an entire file into memcache.

Alternatively, are there any other ways that would be a better idea? I am currently trying to avoid the idea of installing another cache, such as Varnish.

Cheers.

**Edit**

Just to make it clear, I currently use nginx 1.3.0 as my frontend ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to look at:

[Memcached nginx](http://technosophos.com/content/53900-speedup-nginx-drupal-and-memcache-bring-concurrency-and-page-load-time-way-down)

And

[Nginx memcached static files](http://www.kutukupret.com/2011/05/12/nginx-memcached-module-and-php/)